# Crystal Reports DataSource from LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that I want to set the datasource from a stored procedure or a LINQ statement.

This is my LINQ statement

```
 var query = (from TBLBORROWED in db.TBLBORROWEDs
                         join TBLEQUIPMENTDETAIL in db.TBLEQUIPMENTDETAILs on TBLBORROWED.EQUIPMENT_ID equals TBLEQUIPMENTDETAIL.EQUIPMENT_ID
                         join TBLTRANSACTION in db.TBLTRANSACTIONs on TBLBORROWED.TransactionID equals TBLTRANSACTION.TransactionID
                         join TBLEQUIPMENTBARCODE in db.TBLEQUIPMENTBARCODEs on TBLBORROWED.EQUIPMENT_ID equals TBLEQUIPMENTBARCODE.Equipment_ID
                         where TBLBORROWED.TransactionID == TransactionID
                         select new { TBLEQUIPMENTBARCODE.EQBarcodepath, TBLEQUIPMENTDETAIL.EQUIPMENT_ID, TBLEQUIPMENTDETAIL.EQUIPMENT_NAME, TBLBORROWED.Quantity }).ToList();

            if (query!=null)
            {
                BorrowSlip1.SetDataSource(query);
                BorrowSlip1.SetParameterValue("pTransactionID", TransactionID);
                BorrowSlip1.SetParameterValue("pBorrower", Borrower);
                BorrowSlip1.SetParameterValue("pDateBorrowed", TransactionDate);
                BorrowSlip1.SetParameterValue("pProcessedBy", Attendant);
                crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = BorrowSlip1;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ohhhh");
            }
```

It doesn't spit out any syntax errors from intellisense or something but I always encounter this error during runtime

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD9aJ.png)

When I look at the autos of my system. The value of query is not null

[Autos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLNqd.png)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show data types of `EQBarcodepath`, `EQUIPMENT_ID`, `EQUIPMENT_NAME` and `Quantity` properties? I bet you have a property set as `Nullable<T>` and you need to drive returned anonymous type to avoid nullable types.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto string,int,string name

Comment: Are you having `int?`, `long?`, `double?` or `decimal?` type properties inside table classes? Usually this problem raise when you passing null value from those nullable types, and CR report currently not supporting them.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I did, but I also encountered errors. So I just redid the whole thing to work